# Summation by class label without loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix which represents a distances to the k-nearest neighbour of a set of points,
and there is a matrix of class labels of the nearest neighbours. (both N-by-k matrix)

What is the best way WITHOUT explicit python loop (actually, I want to implement this in theano where those loops are not going to work) to build a (N-by-#classes) matrix whose (i,j) element will be the sum of distances from i-th point to its k-NN points with the class label 'j'?

Example:

```
# N = 2
# k = 5
# number of classes = 3

K_val  = np.array([[1,2,3,4,6],
                  [2,4,5,5,7]])

l_val  = np.array([[0,1,2,0,1],
                   [2,0,1,2,0]])

"""
result -> [[5,8,3],
           [11,5,7]]
"""
```

Comment: Personally without a for loop this will be a long `lambda` function...

Comment: I've just replayed to the exactly same problem last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600893/theano-summation-by-class-label/27603816#27603816

Comment: Hmm... is this indeed a duplicate? These seem like two different questions -- one about `numpy` and the other about `theano`. I have no answer for the `theano` question! If you'll edit these two questions to be sufficiently distinct, I'll vote to reopen this.

Comment: @senderle: You're right; I made a mistake in closing it as a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute this with 
[numpy.bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). It
has a `weights` parameter which allows you to count the items in `l_val` 
but weight the items according to `K_val`.

The only little snag is that each row of `K_val` and `l_val` seems to be treated independently. So add a shift to `l_val` so each row has values which are distinct from every other row.

---

```
import numpy as np

num_classes = 3
K_val  = np.array([[1,2,3,4,6],
                  [2,4,5,5,7]])

l_val  = np.array([[0,1,2,0,1],
                   [2,0,1,2,0]])

def label_distance(l_val, K_val):
    nrows, ncols = l_val.shape
    shift = (np.arange(nrows)*num_classes)[:, np.newaxis]
    result = (np.bincount((l_val+shift).ravel(), weights=K_val.ravel(), 
                          minlength=num_classes*nrows)
              .reshape(nrows, num_classes))
    return result


print(label_distance(l_val, K_val))
```

yields

```
[[  5.   8.   3.]
 [ 11.   5.   7.]]
```

---

Although senderle's method is really elegant, using bincount is faster:

```
def using_extradim(l_val, K_val): 
    return (K_val[:,:,None] * (l_val[:,:,None] == numpy.arange(3)[None,None,:])).sum(axis=1)

In [34]: K2 = np.tile(K_val, (1000,1))

In [35]: L2 = np.tile(l_val, (1000,1))

In [36]: %timeit using_extradim(L2, K2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 584 µs per loop

In [40]: %timeit label_distance(L2, K2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Why is ```shift = ...; l_val += shift``` necessary?

Comment: @wwii: Each row of `l_val` is treated separately. If you don't apply a shift to `l_val`, then `np.bincount` will count the unique values in `l_val`, weighted by the corresponding amounts in `K_val` resulting in an array with just 3 bins (since there are only 3 labels, 0, 1 and 2). Since we want 3 bins *per row*, we need to give each row of `l_val` unique labels. (If that is clear as mud, try each step in an interactive session with and without the shift and it will be clear immediately.)

Comment: Wow, much faster! And thanks for the explanation -- I didn't grok the shift right away either.

Comment: I sussed that was the case but wanted to make sure. To use this do you need to know the range of the data, then pick an appropriate shift(s).?

Comment: @wwii: You would need to know the value of `num_classes`, the maximum number of labels in `l_val`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to calculate the values directly. As [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652427/577088)'s tests show, using `bincount` is much faster for large datasets, but I think it's worth knowing how to do this using vanilla broadcasting as well:

```
>>> (K_val[:,:,None] * (l_val[:,:,None] == numpy.arange(3)[None,None,:])).sum(axis=1)
array([[ 5,  8,  3],
       [11,  5,  7]])
```

That's a bit hairy, so I'll step through it slowly. It's probably best to do it this way in code you want to be able to read later! There are four steps:

```
labels = numpy.arange(3)                                   
l_selector = l_val[:,:,None] == labels[None,None,:]
distances = (K_val[:,:,None] * l_selector)
result = distances.sum(axis=1)
```

First we create a list of labels (`labels` above). Then we create a boolean index array:

```
>>> l_selector = l_val[:,:,None] == labels[None,None,:]
```

This expands `l_val` and `labels` into arrays that can be broadcast together. The `None` values (equivalent to `np.newaxis`) add new empty dimensions:

```
>>> l_val[:,:,None].shape
(2, 5, 1)
>>> labels[None,None,:].shape
(1, 1, 3)
```

The dimensions are aligned, so both arrays can be expanded (by repeating the values) along their empty dimensions:

```
>>> l_selector.shape
(2, 5, 3)
```

Now we have a `(n_points, n_neighbors, n_labels)` array, where each column corresponds to a label. (See how each row has only one `True`value?)

```
>>> l_selector
array([[[ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [ True, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

So now we can use this to separate out the distances for each of the three labels. But again, we have to make sure that our arrays are broadcastable, hence the `K_val[:,:,None]` here:

```
>>> distances = (K_val[:,:,None] * l_selector)
>>> distances
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3],
        [4, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 2],
        [4, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 5],
        [7, 0, 0]]])
```

Now all we have to do is sum over the columns.

```
>>> result = distances.sum(axis=1)
>>> result
array([[ 5,  8,  3],
       [11,  5,  7]])
```

You might also consider the transposed approach, which requires a little bit less reshaping:

```
>>> labels = numpy.arange(3)
>>> l_selector = l_val[None,:,:] == labels[:,None,None]
>>> distances = K_val * l_selector
>>> distances.sum(axis=-1)
array([[ 5, 11],
       [ 8,  5],
       [ 3,  7]])
>>> distances.sum(axis=-1).T
array([[ 5,  8,  3],
       [11,  5,  7]])
```